# PHP str_replace twice on output buffer

Tags: php, output, buffer

I would like to perform a couple of regexes on the output buffer, but the following code is not creating the desired affect. I'm wanting to first perform a regex to replace anything enclosed with "{{" and "}}"" which is working fine, but then I would like to minify the HTML output immediately afterwards.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php
ob_start(function($buffer) {
    $viewfile = join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(VIEWS_ROOT, basename(pathinfo(__FILE__)['filename'] . "phtml")));

    if (file_exists($viewfile)) {
        $body = file_get_contents($viewfile);
    } else {
        $body = file_get_contents(join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(VIEWS_ROOT, basename("index.phtml"))));
    }

    preg_replace(array("/\>[^\S ]+/s", "/[^\S ]+\</s", "/(\s)+/s"), array(">", "<", "\\1"), ob_get_contents());

    return (str_replace(array("{{title}}", "{{body}}", "/\>[^\S ]+/s", "/[^\S ]+\</s", "/(\s)+/s"), array("Project", $body, ">", "<", "\\1"), $buffer));
});

require_once(join(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array(LAYOUTS_ROOT, "layout.phtml")));

ob_end_flush();
?>
```

The output is the merging of the following file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
    <link href="css/cosmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    {{body}}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

With:

```
<h1>Hello, World</h1>
```

And I would like the following output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><title>Project</title><link href="css/cosmo.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script><script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script><![endif]--></head><body><h1>Hello, Julian</h1><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script></body></html>
```

Comment: You should provide an example in put and the related desired output.

Comment: @Patrick Q - done

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output I replaced the above return statement with the following:

```
return (preg_replace(array("/\>[^\S]+/s", "/[^\S]+\</s", "/(\s)+/s"), array(">", "<", "\\1"), str_replace(array("{{title}}", "{{body}}"), array("Project", $body), $buffer)));
```